# Can Not Change Merged Cell

Tags: c#, vsto

I am trying to use VSTO to clear the contents of a merged cell.  I get an error of 'Can Not Change Merged Cell'.  Is there a way to clear the contents of a merged cell in VSTO?  This is the code I am using

```
wbExcel = oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wbExcel.ActiveSheet;
sheetExcel.Range["A4, A43, C10, F4"].Clear();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cells aren't part of a merged area, you can use the Range object like you did, otherwise clear the areas one-by-one:

```
sheetExcel.Range["A4"].MergeArea.Clear();
sheetExcel.Range["A43"].MergeArea.Clear();
sheetExcel.Range["C10"].MergeArea.Clear();
sheetExcel.Range["F4"].MergeArea.Clear();
```